# Explanation of new line in htaccess file: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, pki, rewritecond, cpanel

Recently I noticed that a new line was added in the htaccess file in several locations throughout the file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
```

I don't understand what it does, and I would like clarification if possible for its purpose.

An example of how it appears is shown in this example below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking about that one specific _condition_? All those conditions relate to SSL certificate validation when cPanel auto-renews certificates. (More information about that in my answer to another ServerFault question: https://serverfault.com/a/884922/49157) However, where _specifically_, `Ballot169` fits into this picture I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes that one specific condition, and from your answer I agree with you that it does make things really messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really a complete answer, as I can't comment specifically on how/where `Ballot169` fits into the bigger scheme of things. However, I can comment on "what it does". It does seem a bit odd though...

In general, these `RewriteCond` directives are used to create *exceptions* so that when SSL certs are auto-renewed, the necessary validation file can be accessed unencumbered. See [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/884922/49157) to the following ServerFault question for more on this:

- [Apache htaccess multiple rewrite conditions for multiple rules](https://serverfault.com/questions/884915/apache-htaccess-multiple-rewrite-conditions-for-multiple-rules)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
> ```

Since the last part of the regex `(?:\ Ballot169)?` is entirely optional and there is no trailing end-of-string anchor (ie. `$`) then this last part that checks `Ballot169` is entirely superfluous and can be removed! (This "looks like" an error with the regex, unless it is an attempt to inject a comment/trackable token in the code?) So, this is the same as simply:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/
```

In other words, it's checking that the URL-path does not start with `/.well-known/pki-validation/`.

Consequently, this makes the preceding condition that checks against "Comodo" along the same URL-path redundant.

In Googling, this particular directive does crop up as-written in other places, such as [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206804/where-did-these-htaccess-rules-come-from-and-what-exactly-do-they-do) from January 2019.

"Ballot 169" would seem to refer to this:

- [Ballot 169 – Revised Validation Requirements](https://cabforum.org/2016/08/05/ballot-169-revised-validation-requirements/) (effective 1 March 2017)

Comment: I have a response to your answer, but based on its length I can't post it, @MrWhite is there a workaround for that or do I need to add multiple comments?

Comment: If it is itself an answer then you can post it as an answer (it sounds like it probably would be?). Or you can edit your question if it is just additional information to your question. Otherwise multiple comments can be OK, although formatting can be a problem (use backticks for inline code snippets).

Comment: ...Or it could even be added to my answer - if it relates directly to it?

Comment: @KennethPovedaMata I approved the edit, however, I think it should really be an answer of its own (just referencing my answer). (It makes sense as a separate answer, as you are commenting on your own experiences and this adds value.) If you do that then I'll be able to comment on the specific points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@MrWhite I appreciate your guidance on how to respond, add more context etc, and per your suggestion I am answering my question so you can add your comments to it, thank you.

<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>:<:>

After your answer I contacted the hosting company, the representative only said that it was part of the SSL certificate at first, I kept asking him what is the purpose and its function, the only thing he said was "it all has to do with how the certificate was installed", when I kept pushing he backtracked on that comment saying it was not important.

The way you broke down the directive and how it works for me, and from the other answer that you linked that says "other people have labeled this particular set of rules as some sort of DDOS protection", got me thinking, so I did a search on 'well-known hack' which came up with this:

https://www.zscaler.com/blogs/research/abuse-hidden-well-known-directory-https-sites

So your analysis makes me think that protection of the certificate and possibly the directory is what that line does by either blocking or redirecting such requests, correct me if I am wrong.

Again I became curious and started downloading access logs and searching through them for 'well-known' entries, to be honest I didn't know if those were common (as in there always, but I never paid attention to them) or not common, and this is what I found.

- On February there were a total of 280 entries in the access logs that looked similar to this line below, the string of numbers after /acme-challenge/ is different for all of them, and the majority point to ip addresses from Cloudflare (the website uses Cloudflare, so I am not sure if this is important to mention or not).

**"GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/Z152-H592V1UDY0PWBCKU3GEO5L6-3DQ HTTP/1.1" 200 64 "-" "Cpanel-HTTP-Client/1.0"**

- On March no entries at all, but they started showing again for this month of April which also coincides with the new line being added, and so far there are around 145 entries for 'well-known'.
- Worth noting that this particular website uses the free ssl from Cloudflare not the one from Let's Encrypt
- And last but not least, from 3 different accounts that I have access to and using the same hosting company only in 1 of them is where that line is being added to the .htaccess file.

Mr. White thank you so much as always for your insight, if I do find any additional information I'll post it here.

Comment: Those URLs come during validation of certificates by any CA using ACME, the major one currently being Let's Encrypt. But based on the UserAgent in the string I would think this is a WebPanel (CPanel) testing if the validation is in place before sending it to Let's Encrypt. It can be as well someone else that did a mistake and used your domain as a typo or something, hence generating validation attempts towards you. This is mostly noise and not very important indeed...

Comment: Also if you want another layer of security for your X.509 (not SSL, that died 20 years ago) you can use DNS CAA records. All CAs are mandated to check them. If you use them and do not list Let's Encrypt there, then Let's Encrypt will never generate a certificate for your domain.